# i want to know what is this window in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]

it's a youtube app and I want to know how to add the configuration window

Comment: Those are menu items: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called **overflow menu**.

See the image and its description below: [Google Design Guidelines - Menu](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-usage).

> - The action overflow in the app bar will emit a menu.
> - This particular action overflow menu contains four menu items: Refresh, Help & feedback, Settings, and Sign out.